# Converting int32_t to float

Tags: c

I've seen a lot of questions about converting from float to int32_T, but none that address converting a int32_t to float.

The data that I am working with is in centimeters. So I just want to confirm that there won't be any type conversion issues if I try to convert them to floats.

The reason that I am interested in this conversion, is that a function I am using works only with floating point numbers. So if I pass the function int32_t's and it is expecting floats, will it automatically typecast my arguments?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5):

If you pass an `int32_t` to a function that takes a `float` parameter by value, then there will be an implicit cast (type conversion). One caveat though is that an IEEE754 single precision `float` has less precision than a 32 bit int (it has approximately 24 bits of precision, versus 32 for an `int32_t`), so you may lose some accuracy if you're using large values.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t sqr(int32_t x)
{
    return x * x;
}

float sqrf(float x)
{
    return x * x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int32_t x = 9999;

    printf("sqr(%d) = %d, sqrf(%d) = %f\n", x, sqr(x), x, sqrf(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall int_float_prec.c && ./a.out
sqr(9999) = 99980001, sqrf(9999) = 99980000.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to float before passing to function

```
int32_t i=32;

func((double) i);
```